# Optimizer bug or undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using u16 = unsigned short int;
using s16 = signed short int;
using s32 = signed int;

s16 Algorithm(s16 sample)
{
    s32 absSample = static_cast<s32>(abs(sample));
    s32 sampleBits = absSample >> 7;
    s32 sampleMasked = absSample & 0x7F;

    s16 result = (u16)(sampleMasked << sampleBits)  | (u16)(1 << (sampleBits - 2));
    if (sample < 0)
    {
        result = -result;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    s16 result = Algorithm(-63);
    if (result == -63)
    {
        printf("OK!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("BUG!?\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

In x64 debug it prints "OK!" but in x64 release it prints "BUG!?", is there a problem with my code or is the compiler doing something wrong here? How can I fix or workaround this issue?

Comment: Just making sure, do you have the hotfix for update 3 (assuming you are using MSVC 2015)?

Comment: I'm on update 2 currently, is this something fixed in update 3?

Comment: I am not too sure, I just thought it might be relevant.

Comment: Those types should probably be `uint16_t`, `int16_t`, and `int32_t`, right? Since `signed int` isn't guaranteed to be 32 bits?

Comment: x64 Release (all the default settings) with MSVC 2015 Update 3 seems to give `OK`.

Comment: So then its a compiler issue? I still get BUG!? if I change the types to uint16_t etc

Comment: @paulm, well, you could put the generated assembly here since it's not that much to see how it differs from MSVC 2015 Update 3. Also, have you changed any compiler/linker settings?

Comment: I mean, your example triggers UB, but still, it weird that it differs, even though once you deal with UB anything can happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the value `-63` triggers undefined behavior (`sampleBits` will be 0 thus you will be shifting -2 places) anything can happen:)

Comment: Added a check so the shift value is limited to 0 and both now produce the correct value